# Genereating function of $H_{2n}$

Tags: calculus, summation, harmonic-numbers

We know the generating function of: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}H_nx^n=\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x-1}$$.

How do we find out the generating function of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}H_{2n}x^n$$

I used the formula: $\displaystyle { H }_{ 2n }=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left[ { H }_{ n }+{ H }_{ n-\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  } \right] +\ln { 2 } $. But that didn't help.

Comment: $\sum H_{2n}x^{n}=\sum H_{n}x^{n}-\sum H_{2n-1}x^{n}$

Comment: what is H? heaviside function?

Comment: @juliogodoy. Harmonic numbers (look at the tags).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}H_{2n}x^{n}} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}H_{2n}x^{2n/2} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}H_{n}x^{n/2}\,{1 + \pars{-1}^{n} \over 2}
\\[3mm] & =
\half\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}H_{n}\pars{\root{x}}^{n} +
\half\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}H_{n}\pars{-\root{x}}^{n}
\\[3mm] & =
\color{#f00}{-\,\half\bracks{{\ln\pars{1 - \root{x}} \over 1 - \root{x}} +
{\ln\pars{1 + \root{x}} \over 1 + \root{x}}}}
\end{align}

Comment: congratulations, very creative your answer, but why you put $H_{n}$ intead $H_{2n}$?

Comment: @juliogodoy The second one shows the sum over the even indexes. The third one sum over all $n \geq 1$ but the factor $\left[1 + \left(-1\right)^{n}\right]/2$ selects the even indexes. It's because we know the $H_{n}$ generating function and we want to take advantage of this fact.

Comment: you are a genius

Comment: @juliogodoy Thanks. I don't think so. It's just practical tools I was using for  maaaaaa,,,aaany years.

Comment: is good see latin people with talent, that make me proud.

Answer (score 3):

Define $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty H_{2n} x^{2n}, \quad g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty H_{2n-1} x^{2n-1}.$$  Then since $$H_{2n} = H_{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n},$$ we have $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty H_{2n} x^{2n} = x \sum_{n=1}^\infty H_{2n-1} x^{2n-1} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{2n} = x g(x) - \frac{1}{2}\log(1-x^2).$$  But since $$f(x) + g(x) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty H_m x^m = \frac{\log(1-x)}{x-1} = h(x),$$ we have $$f(x) = x (h(x) - f(x)) - \frac{1}{2} \log(1-x^2),$$ or $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x} \left( x h(x) - \frac{\log (1-x^2)}{2} \right).$$  Then the desired sum is simply $$f(x^{1/2}) = \frac{2 x^{1/2} \tanh^{-1} x^{1/2} - \log(1-x)}{2(1-x)} $$ which is a straightforward algebraic exercise.